# near by location using lat long - google api - php

Tags: php, google-maps, geolocation

I have thousands of property in my store. I'm trying to write **automated related properties**. Each property has **latitude** and **longitude**. When customer click anyone property, we need to suggest five top most near by properties as related properties we have.

I'm working in php framework so I expect php related answer.

can anyone point me right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 5;
```

Here's the SQL statement that will find the closest 20 locations that are within a radius of 25 miles to the 37, -122 coordinate. It calculates the distance based on the latitude/longitude of that row and the target latitude/longitude, and then asks for only rows where the distance value is less than 25, orders the whole query by distance, and limits it to 20 results. To search by kilometers instead of miles, replace 3959 with 6371.

for more details [click here](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know(I haven't been using google maps recently), google maps doesn't provide this type of solution.

I believe you're in need of a spacial database; if you're currently using an RDBMS check out the postgis extension for Postgresql:

http://postgis.net/

Here's a good list of references for using postgis and spacial data:

http://twiav-tt.blogspot.ca/2012/07/postgis-using-latitude-and-longitude-to.html
http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/spatial_relationships.html#st-distance-and-st-dwithin
http://revenant.ca/www/postgis/workshop/indexing.html

If you're using Mongo, there's also Mongogis:

https://github.com/mongogis

I've never worked with Mongogis so I don't have any good references.